# How can I programmatically add a Win32Console (c ++) project in visual studio 2017?

Tags: visual-studio-2017

Good morning.

I am working on creating a solution and adding projects through DTE in Visual Studio 2017.

VisualStudio worked fine until 2015, but from 2017, we changed the method and it does not work properly.

Until VisualStudio 2015, the following code was used.

## Visual Studio 2015

```
CComPtr<EnvDTE::Project> temp;
CComBSTR pPath;
pSolution->get_TemplatePath(
    CComBSTR("{8BC9CEB8-8B4A-11D0-8D11-00A0C91BC942}"), // C++
    &pPath);
pPath.Append("Win32console.vsz");                       // Use C++ Win32Console Application
```

Result :
pPath is C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcprojects

## Visual Studio 2017

```
CComPtr<EnvDTE::Project> temp;
CComBSTR pPath;
pSolution->get_TemplatePath(
    CComBSTR("{8BC9CEB8-8B4A-11D0-8D11-00A0C91BC942}"), // C++
    &pPath);
```

pPath is C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\VC\vcprojects

However, 2017 does not have a file like Win32console.vsz in that directory, so you can not add projects to the solution like 2015.

If the method has changed, will you be able to get some documentation or help?

Comment: Please try to give us a [MCVE]

Comment: @GrantGarrison Sorry. I made the question a bit more simple.